# Background images after a certain alphabetical point not displaying on local build?

Tags: css, eclipse, tomcat

This is the second version of a recent question which I deleted, with greater insight as to the direction of the problem. It's not code-related.

With no apparent trigger (no changes made on the developer's part), the majority of images used for CSS `background` attribute in a web-app spontaneously stopped displaying.

Inspection showed two things: the browser could see the CSS pointing to all the images correctly, and second, that the dozen or so images which displayed correctly happened to be the first dozen or so resource files when listed alphabetically.

**When I changed the name of a file that was not displaying so that it preceded the alphabetical drop-off, it started displaying perfectly.**

**If I run an identical copy of the code hosted off my neighbor's machine, it works perfectly.**

This is completely beyond my ken. Any ideas? I don't even know why this started happening, it worked perfectly for months until this appeared out of nowhere. Mark you, YES, I have cleared the cache and cookies and every relevant similar thing repeatedly.

Comment: Any chance we can see this in action?

Comment: Only happens on my local machine. If I load an identical copy of the app hosted from my neighbor developer's machine, works perfectly.

Comment: Please troubleshoot this black box for me....

Comment: Believe me I know, I'm just at such a loss I'm throwing random ideas off walls or hoping someone will be like *That happened to me once! It was crazy but it turned out to be because...*. I mean, I even changed some files' names arbitrarily by just sticking an X in the middle of their name and they started working.

Comment: It sounds an awful lot like a cache issue.  You said you cleared the cache - just checking but did you clear the Firefox cache specifically (from within FF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the problem was solved by copying all the resource files to a different folder, deleting them from the project, then replacing them with the copies. Some insane caching bug somewhere. This all happened in Eclipse.

A colleague suggested next time I try cleaning the Tomcat server, so maybe try that too!